# Как запретить скачивание аудио, если ссылка прямая?

Tags: html

Имеется страница, на которой есть прямая ссылка на аудиофайл:

```
<p>
<a href="ссылка.mp3">Название файла</a>
</p>
```

Нажав на ссылку, пользователя переводит на новую вкладку и аудио можно прослушать. Однако есть требование, что кнопки "Скачать" у плеера быть не должно (она появляется вместе со скоростью воспроизведения, когда нажимаешь на троеточие).

Вопрос: как запретить пользователю скачивать файл через кнопку "Скачать", если ссылка ведет прямо на файл?

Если была бы отдельная страница, то понятно, что можно использовать атрибут `nodowload`, но как его добавить, если отдельной страницы на файл нет, а только ссылка на него?

Код страницы, когда открываешь ссылку:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 </head>
 <body>
   <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="ссылка.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   </video>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: запретить доступ по ссылке и сделать свой проигрыватель который будет открывать файл

Comment: @InDevX , спасибо за предложения. Человек хочет, чтобы была прямая ссылка на аудио, без создания дополнительных страниц, поэтому запретить доступ по ссылке в данной задаче невозможно. Отсюда вопрос: если создать свой проигрыватель, то при переходе по прямой ссылке, CSS и JS не подцепятся и пользователь все равно будет видеть стандартный проигрыватель?

Comment: Запретить по ссылке, имею ввиду чтобы файл в любом месте по ссылке не открывался. А открывать его по этой же ссылке будет кастомный проигрыватель, куда что угодно навешать можно, и на вид его можно сделать таким же, как стандартный, но стандартный у каждого браузера свой